# Life of an object created inside a method definition

Tags: java

I'm having a doubt regarding the life of an object which is created inside a method definition. As far as I know, all the variable's life, local to a method, ends with the completion of that method. So if I create an object inside a method, will it be destroyed after the execution of that method.

Comment: The object will be garbage collected at some point after no more live references to it exist. This is not necessarily exactly at the point when the last reference to is lost.

Comment: Ok thanks **@pvg**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An object will become *eligible* for garbage collection as soon as the runtime can prove it will never again be accessed. It will actually be collected sometime after that, whenever the runtime finds it convenient.

Note that object lifetime is not governed by **scope**, which is a syntactic construct, but by **reachability**. An object can stop being *reachable* while the method is still executing (e.g. when no line of code that touches the object remains to be executed), or it may continue to be *reachable* long after the method returns (e.g. if a reference to the object is stored in a static field or returned from the method).

Raymond Chen wrote a great blog post about this called [When is an object eligible for garbage collection?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100810-00/?p=13193) It's about C#, not Java, but similar principles apply.

Comment: Also relevant http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#escapeAnalysis in that in cases similar to what is described in the question, allocation and garbage collection might be optimized away altogether.

Comment: Thanks very much **@Daniel Pryden**

Answer (score 3):

Once that execution goes out of the scope within which the object has been created, or another assignment operation takes place, and there are no references to said object, the runtime will mark that object for garbage collection (meaning that the object *might* still be there, just no longer accessible).

The actual time when the object is destroyed (garbage collected) depends on other factors, such as overall memory consumption for the application.

Comment: You don't actually know what is going to happen to the object once it is no longer live - this depends a lot on the type of GC in use. There's certainly no requirement that an object be 'marked' for GC once the final reference goes out of scope. In many cases, nothing will happen at that point.

Comment: This answer is incorrect: an object can become eligible for GC while a reference to it is still in scope, so long as the runtime can prove that reference will never again be read.

Comment: @DanielPryden: You mean when you assign to `null`?

Comment: @npinti: You don't need to assign null to the reference or otherwise overwrite it. If the JIT reuses the slot in the frame for another value, the object becomes eligible for collection. The runtime is smarter than you think. :-)

Comment: @DanielPryden: Thanks for the information, updating the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the local variable.If the local variable is assigned to a global scope it will not be destroyed till the global scope is nullified.

For example you have a instance class like (just pseudo)

```
    class A {

    }

    class B {
    A a;

    public B() {

    }

    public void init(){
      A a = new A();
      this.a = a;
    }

    public void destroyA() {
      this.a = null;
    }

    }

    class C {
     B b;

    public C(){
       this.b = new B();
       b.init();
    }
  }
```

We are creating a local variable A and assign it the global reference so even after the execution of init it would hold the reference. Once the destoryA() is called the reference would be nullified.